# Unable to Load PDF File in the Webview

Tags: java, android, pdf

i have a question. I developed a project with webview component but i cannot display pdf files in the webview, because in the website link all pdf files opened with new tab and pdf file is authentication with user session. I tested this website link on the Official Android Chrome app all pdf files is opened and automatically downloaded PDF files in the mobile storage but on webview component i cannot display this.
Please could you help me for this topic. Thanks in advance.
My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView = null;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    this.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
   String DESKTOP_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36";
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USER_AGENT);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

            } 

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
                intent.setDataAndType( videoUri, "application/pdf" );
                intent.setPackage( "com.example.webview" );
                startActivity( intent );

            view.loadUrl(url);
                return true; // to tell the WebView that it should not load the URL because you handled it by yourself

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) { 
            showDefaultError();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

            } 
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    });

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

        //put your code here if your want to show the progress with progressbar
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(“MY LINK”);
```

Comment: A WebView indeed cannot display a pdf document. A WebView is for displaying html documents.

Comment: Thank you so  much @blackapps but do you have any alternative way to view or download  such as to download autamtically pdf files? I tried this to download but for Session issue i connot to download this, do you have any idea about this topic?

Comment: You can download that file like any other file and save to phone storage and use ACTION_VIEW to let the user choose a pdf viewer.

Comment: You could also forward the pdf url to a google pdf to html convert service and display the html in your webview.